# Shopping cart, how can I caclulate the total price of all the items in my cart

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies

I have successfully been able to add to the basket using flask Sessions but I am having trouble with calculating the total price of all the products. I have tried to set a variable which calculates the price using the value in the list but that doesn't work and returns the first item instead. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
@app.route("/Menu")
def menu():
    MenuItems = Menu.query.all()
    return render_template("menu.html", MenuItems=MenuItems)

@app.route("/AddToCart", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def addToCart():
    itemId = int(request.form.get("productId"))
    MenuItem = Menu.query.get(itemId)

    if MenuItem is None:
        return render_template("error.html", errorMessage="There has been an issue adding this item to your basket")

    sVars = session['cart']

    sVars.append([str(MenuItem.ItemName), float(MenuItem.ItemPrice)])
    session['cart'] = sVars

    allPrices = sum(sVars[1])

    return render_template("cart.html", cartSession=session['cart'], allPrices=allPrices)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've got a list that looks like:

```
sVars = [
    ['apple', 2.12],
    ['orange', 3.13],
]
```

We just need a list of the second element of each list, that way we can do `sum([2.12, 3.13])` and get our result.  A neat way to do that is with a list comprehension:

```
total_price = sum([x[1] for x in sVars])
print(total_price)
```

Which is a (in my humble opinion) neater way of doing:

```
total_price = 0
for entry in sVars:
    total_price += entry[1]
print(total_price)
```

As a secondary note-- generally Python recommends your variables are all lowercase `svars` compared to `sVars` using `_` for spacing like `total_price` rather then `totalPrice` and leave the `CamelCasing` for class names, like you've got with `MenuItem`.  It'll make your code a little easier for other people to look at and work with.

Comment: Thanks this has worked! Is this method of adding to a basket ok or is there a better method of doing this?

Comment: Your method is fine-- if I were to do it, I would make a few little changes. Like I would just store the reference (e.g. say Banana's primary key/reference is 4011) so I would just store that id and quantity in the session-- then use the server to look up the pricing/description etc.  (It would deal with the issue if your site changed a product price/description etc, the session would still have the old one)